# Setting Vimperator external editor file extension (for vim filetype)

Tags: macos, firefox, vim

I currently have the following as part of my Vimperator configuration to use MacVim (gvim) to edit text fields:

```
editor=/bin/bash -lc "mvim -f \$*" mvim
```

This works well, but the temporary file it creates has a .tmp extension and I would like to give it a different extension so that I can have Vim associate that with a filetype and thus set up a bunch of options made for editing.

Is there a configuration in Vimperator or Vim that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question is what extension would you associate it with?

Since it's just a text field, there isn't really any way for any part of the system to know what you intend it to be (that is, what you're editing); is it C code?  Is it mediawiki?  Is it a facebook comment?, etc.

Given that, I can think of two solutions:

1. If there's only one filetype you care about for this sort of thing, just tell vim about it: `autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost *.tmp setl filetype=wibble`
2. If there are lots, make key bindings so you can change easily once you've opened the file; `map F1 :setl filetype=wibble`

Those would both go in your vimrc.

-Robin

Comment: Thanks...I didn't think of it this way. I was thinking in the manner of quickcursor in which you define the extension of the temp file passed to the editor based on the application it is coming from, so I could just define those with a .md extension and the correct filetype would be set. This is more versatile!